# How do I create a class library for Windows Phone 8? Visual Studio keeps creating 8.1 project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.  I have fallen into a trap where I can't seem to create a new Windows Phone 8.0 class library for a solution I have that is currently all Windows Phone 8.0 projects.  Every time I use Project -> New to create the class library project, it is always targeted towards Windows Phone 8.1 and there is no option anywhere to target it for Windows Phone 8.0.  Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You can't.  You need VS 2012 for Windows 8.0 projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Visual Studio 2012 and the Windows Phone 8.0 SDK.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471

Visual Studio 2013 will only let you develop 8.1 apps. Besides, that I'm not sure if the app store will accept 8.0 apps anymore. You might be stuck with doing version 8.1 apps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot.  The solution contains several WinPhone 8.0 projects and I really don't want to upgrade everything at the moment.

Comment: I personally think 8.1 is worth the upgrade. There are many welcomed improvements to both the SDK API's and the OS. :-)